# Keycloak redirects to login on page refresh

Tags: angular5, keycloak

I am using keycloak JavaScript adapter in my Angular 5 app and whilst my login and redirection works, the problem is that whenever I refresh my ng app it will again ask for keycloak login altough I see that my session is still active on /auth/realms/{image a realm name}/account.

As I have understood it from the keycloak JS Adapter documentation https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.0/securing_apps/topics/oidc/javascript-adapter.html, when onLoad is set to login-required for init options it authenticates the client if the user is logged-in to Keycloak or display the login page if not. But it seems like, in my case, that it takes one second to log me out because it always redirects me to the keycloak's login page.

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same problem as you.

Comment: Yes, I did find a solution but I don't really remember it. I think it was because of our system architecture where we had a layer for handling authentication and authorization so the urls, that I'd got, weren't working because of a missed configuration in our system.

Answer (score 18):

You need to pass the saved token from previous login to keycloak init constructor. If you are using Authorization Flow (standard) then refresh token as well. Like this.

```js
// load previous tokens, saved after successful login of keycloak success callback
    const token = localStorage.getItem('kc_token');
    const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('kc_refreshToken');
    // pass to keycloak init
    keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'login-required', token, refreshToken }).then(
    success=>{
      localStorage.setItem('kc_token', keycloak.token);
      localStorage.setItem('kc_refreshToken', keycloak.refreshToken);
      //load your app from here
  });
```

Comment: do not use local storage to store a token. https://dev.to/rdegges/please-stop-using-local-storage-1i04

Comment: @Stuck But KC-tokens are already available to the browser if you look at the network requests and they are only valid for X seconds. How does storing it in either local or session storage make it worse?

Comment: Seems to be still actual in 2023

Comment: @Stianhn By storing it in local storage, you retain the token forever. One thing that would happen is that, if you close a tab but then later go back to the same site, you'd still be logged in. That's very counter-intuitive for users, because they expect to be logged out once they close the tab.

Answer (score 1):

Tl;dr: In my code, there were several reasons why the init function was not called a second time with the parameters. Look out for that!

Fwiw, I had a similar problem, and it seems to me I solved the issue (for now). In addition to *@ahmadalibaloch*'s answer (passing the known tokens to the init), I followed this neat guide here: https://dev.to/matejbucek/secure-svelte-with-keycloak-42g3 (for svelte-kit though), where the checkParams function checks for the redirect url to call the init function again (with the tokens).

Two things lead to that malfunction in my code, which you could look for and try to fix, caused by a custom search parameter within in the redirect url like so:

```
mypage.tld/foo?myparam=0#keycloak-redirect-params
```

This way, the checkParams function didn't work correctly. But also, `myparam=0` was used as an alternate access string (think link sharing), so my code gave up on keycloak before it was ready (the second time), i.e. the init function was not called again and the search param used instead. My advice: If the other answers don't suffice, try to find out why the init function isn't called again as it should be.

I know this is super specific, but it was hard enough to spot this (for me), so maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to login into your `keycloak` client select the realm, navigate to the `AUTHENTICATION` tab on the sidebar, select the `FLOW` menu tab then change the cookie settings to alternative or required.

[image: An image showing Flow menu bar settings]

Answer (score 0):

keycloak js stores only in memory. They did the choice for security reason.

But the issue is that it's not resiliant to refresh or new tab.

So if you want to be resilent two possible approaches

OWASP recommandation is sessionStorage (https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/JSON_Web_Token_for_Java_Cheat_Sheet.md#token-storage-on-client-side)
Better than storageLocale before more limited

You can also follow this big article with a nice matrix of risks where they recommend cookies https://thenewstack.io/best-practices-for-storing-access-tokens-in-the-browser/
With drawback of more exposure to network attack

But in all case the solution is the one above of @ahmadalibaloch

But don't forget to update the store also at refresh of token and clean the sotrage at logout