# Where does keycloak-js adapter store the refresh token and access token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak

For the authorization code flow with [keycloak javascript adapter](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/securing_apps/topics/oidc/javascript-adapter.html), it seems that the tokens (access tokens and refresh tokens) are stored on the client side. But I can't seem to find where is it stored? I've looked at Local Storage and Session Storage, but its not there.

Answer (score 1):

I think it stores it in memory - see the answer below from the project lead:

https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-dev/2016-July/007654.html

Answer (score 1):

keycloak js stores only in memory. They did the choice for security reason.

But the issue is that it's not resiliant to refresh or new tab.

So if you want to be resilent two possible approaches

OWASP recommandation is sessionStorage (https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/JSON_Web_Token_for_Java_Cheat_Sheet.md#token-storage-on-client-side) Better than storageLocale before more limited

You can also follow this big article with a nice matrix of risks where they recommend cookies https://thenewstack.io/best-practices-for-storing-access-tokens-in-the-browser/ With drawback of more exposure to network attack

So after authentication, store refresh end access token to the appropriate storage, when updating also, remove them at logout and at init retreive them from storage and add them to init command

So you can look at a partial code sample but with not recommanded storage here:  [Keycloak redirects to login on page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50580338/keycloak-redirects-to-login-on-page-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

The Keycloak JS Adapter stores data in the Local Storage or in a cookie if Local Storage is not available :

Snippet from the [source code](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/35ecaf07cb07fba0d9ebcea20cb0e5c76c13b0a4/adapters/oidc/js/src/main/resources/keycloak.js#L1724) :

```js
function createCallbackStorage() {
  try {
    return new LocalStorage();
  } catch (err) {}
  return new CookieStorage();
}
```

Comment: Isn't it super unsafe to store the refresh token in the localstorage? Wouldn't it be better to store in a httponly (!) cookie?

Comment: Why would it be unsafe ? It's a short lived value, and you would be able to retrieve it from the network console when it's being sent anyway.

Comment: Only if you use token rotation and a refresh token is only usable once. Otherwise every js lib could steal the refresh token and get unlimited new access tokens... And the refresh token is not short lived by design, otherwise I would be logged out every time I don't use the app for like 5 minutes ^^

Comment: If you check the code this is only used to store the callbacks I assume for the PKCE etc. Not for the actual tokens.

Comment: Its wrong code sample: this code sample is only for the keycloak status init element  (like nonce)

Comment: AFAIK, refresh token is saved in memory and session token is save in httponly cookie. When the user tries to get access token with refresh token, the session token is also required to get the access token. So even if someone gets hold on to the refresh token, they wont be able to generate new access tokens.